# Recursively find files in a directory having file size greater then 1 GB

Tags: shell, unix

I am beginner to UNIX and shell scripting.

I wrote below command to find disk usage of file systems which are greater than 1GB

```
Command: df -h| sed "s/%//g"|awk 'NR>1 {print $0}'| awk '{if($(NF-1) >90) {print $NF" Alert:Disk out of space "$(NF-1)"%"}}'
```

Now I need a shell script to find all files which are greater than 1gb at this filesystems by using loop
I tried with below script but I am getting some error

```
df -h| sed "s/%//g"|awk 'NR>1 {print $0}'| awk '{if($(NF-1) >90) {print $NF" Alert:Disk out of space "$(NF-1)"%"}}' > disk_usage
while read -r line;
do
Path= echo "$line"
cd path
find . -size +1G -exec du -h {} \;| sort -nr
done < "$disk_usage"
```

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 1):

May be this could help you to get the details of files having size greater then 1G

```
find "$(pwd)" -type f -name "*.*" -size +1G
```

Reference : https://thispointer.com/linux-find-files-larger-than-given-size/

Answer (score 0):

> I tried with below script but I am getting some error

- To prevent `df` from wrapping output with long filesystem names in two lines, you should use option `-P` (*POSIX output format*) if supported.
- You write temporary output to `disk_usage`, but try to read from `$disk_usage` - to avoid such mistakes, just use a pipe.
- You `read -r line` containing the path and other text, but fail to extract the path whereto you want to `cd`; better `read path rest`, doing the extraction right there.
- Write `cd $path` rather than `cd path`, or use `$path` instead of `.` with `find`.

This gives:

```
df -hP | … | awk '{if ($(NF-1) > 90) {print $NF" Alert:Disk out of space "$(NF-1)"%"}}' |
while read path rest
do  echo $path $rest
    …
done
```